# Do I need to initialize an iOS empty nested array that's part of a plist import?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

the code below is working, but I want to make sure it's *correct*. I'm nervous about having an empty Array inside my dictionary that I create from the plist, since typically it seems that if you don't, say, `initWithCapacity:1` then you often get memory errors once you start trying to add items.

At least, that's been my experience with NSMutableDictionary. However, this is the first time I'm trying to implement nested data objects, so perhaps the reason this code works is that the nested array is automatically initialized when it's imported as part of its parent dictionary?

Any and all comments appreciated. Thanks.

First, here's what the plist looks like that I'm using to create my dictionary:

[image: someData.plist]

Next, here's my code where I'm using the plist to create a dictionary, then adding an item to `dataArray`

```
// Create a pointer to a dictionary

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;

// Read "SomeData.plist" from application bundle

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SomeData.plist"];
dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];


// Now let's see if we can successfully add an item to the end of this empty nested array. How 'bout the number 23

NSNumber *yetAnotherNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:23];

[[dictionary objectForKey:@"dataArray"] addObject:yetAnotherNumber];

// Dump the contents of the dictionary to the console

NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);
```

Okay, fine, simple, good. When I Log the dictionary contents it shows that "23" has been added as an array value to `dataArray`. So the code works. But again, I want to confirm that I'm not "getting lucky" here, with my code just happening to work even though I'm not properly initializing that nested array. If so, then I could run into unanticipated errors later on.

So to sum up, `dataArray` is an empty array inside the .plist, so do I need to initialize it somehow (using, for example `initWithCapacity:` or something else) before I can properly populate it, or is the way I'm coding here just fine?

Thanks again.

**EDIT**

Hey all. I've been doing continued research on this, in the interests of finding a satisfying answer. I think I may have stumbled upon something, via [this link on deep copying](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=895). His [previous posts on deep copying](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=213) had presented some code to do essentially what I was looking for above: create a mutable copy of a dictionary or array, from a plist, that also has mutable sub-structures.

However, as mentioned in the link above, it looks like these methods were superfluous, due to the [`CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPropertyListRef/Reference/reference.html) method, which can be invoked with a call such as

```
testData = CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path], kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves);
```

So, my question is, can I properly use `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy`, in the way shown, to achieve what I've been asking about here? In other words, can I use this method to import my dictionary from a plist with fully mutable, nested data objects?

As I mentioned in one of the comments, I know I can create a nested, mutable dictionary manually, but for complex data that's just not practical, and it seems unlikely that built-in methods to import a mutable plist don't exist. So, based on the above, it looks like I've possibly found the solution, but I'm still too new to this to be able to say for sure. Please advise.

(Side note: I would simply test the code, but as we've established, the current SDK is buggy with regard to allow you to edit immutable nested dictionaries, contrary to the documented behavior. So as before, I'm not just interested in whether this works, but whether it's *correct*)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the code you posted, it seems odd that it works; the call to `addObject:` should cause an exception to be thrown, because the object stored under the key `dataArray` is an instance of `NSArray`, not `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Interesting point. To confirm that it's functioning as a mutable array I tried adding another number in addition to "23" that I add in the code above. Using `addObject:`. It still works. So yeah, there's definitely some stuff going on under-the-hood here that I don't understand yet.

Comment: It's definitely undocumented behavior, and feels like it might actually be a framework bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object in a dictionary which is created by reading from disk will be properly initialized. You will not have to do it on your own. However, as pointed out by jlehr, [contents of the dictionary should be immutable](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithContentsOfFile%3a). If you want the contents of the dictionary to be mutable, you will need to change them on your own. I have no idea why your program is not throwing an exception.

I do not know why you are getting memory errors while not using `initWithCapacity:1` in other situations. The following code is perfectly valid:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:@"object1"];
[array addObject:@"object2"];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
[array release];
```

If you don't specify a capacity, the array won't pre-allocate any memory, but it will allocate memory as required later.

**Edit**:

It is perfectly acceptable to use NSDictionary with `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy`. In Core Foundation, a CFPropertyList can be a CFDictionary, CFArray, CFNumber, CFString, or CFData. Since NSDictionary is [toll-free bridged](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW98) to CFDictionary, you can use it wherever a CFDictionary is asked for by casting, and vice-versa. Your code as is will give a warning, but you can suppress it by casting the dictionary and return values.

```
NSDictionary *testData = (NSDictionary*)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path], kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves);
```

Comment: Actually, turns out I was incorrect: when creating an instance of a mutable collection by reading a plist, any nested collections will also be mutable.

Comment: @jlehr Can you post your source? The link I posted is the `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` reference, and at the end of the description section it says, "The objects contained by this dictionary are immutable, even if the dictionary is mutable."

Comment: @ughoavgfhw RE: your answer; I guess I meant initializing in general. Whether w/ capacity:1 or just init. I've gotten in the habit of initializing w/ capacity since Mutable Dictionaries I've created in other code seem to be temperamental otherwise. Regarding your comment: this begs the question of why my code is working. If the nested Array (which I created using plist editor, as shown in screenshot) is immutable, it shouldn't be letting me add to it, but it is. Hence the question and the riddle, etc =P

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Indeed, as you said, the class reference you link to states "The objects contained by this dictionary are immutable, even if the dictionary is mutable." So this is really weird. Why is my nested array behaving as though it's mutable? This is what I *want* it to do, of course, but if I'm handling it incorrectly I want to correct my technique to avoid unforeseen consequences...

Comment: @Murdock said: "I've gotten in the habit of initializing w/ capacity since Mutable Dictionaries I've created in other code seem to be temperamental otherwise." It doesn't pay to be superstitious. ;-)  There's nothing magical about `initWithCapacity:`. If your code is misbehaving, it's best to pinpoint the actual reason.

Comment: Haha, yeah point noted. It's more a prioritization as I learn the language. I can only "dig deep" into so many issues as once, so some things get bumped to the category of "hack it together till I can understand it better"

Comment: I can relate. :-) Anyway, the behavior of instances of `NSMutableDictionary` is consistent regardless of the way they're initialized, so perhaps you were running into issues with something else -- memory management, for example.

Comment: Hey guys, please see my edit to my original post for an update on this. Would still appreciate some feedback. Thanks!

Comment: @Murdock Yes, that is OK. I'll edit my post to elaborate on this, but you probably should have asked a new question since it is a different topic: Can you use NSDictionary with CFPropertyList functions.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Point noted. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2):

`init...` methods should only be called once, immediately after a call to `alloc` or `allocWithZone:`. When framework code creates and returns an object or graph of objects, their `init...` methods have already been called, so sending another `init...` message would have undefined results. Don't do that.

Interestingly, in spite of what the documentation appears to say (and admittedly I probably missed a key sentence or paragraph somewhere), when you create an instance of a mutable collection by reading a plist, any nested collections are also mutable. I ran the following little experiment in a test harness just to be sure:

```
NSMutableDictionary *pets = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/Pets.plist"];
NSMutableArray *cats = [pets objectForKey:@"cats"];

[cats addObject:@"Foo"]; // EDIT: Added line I accidentally omitted earlier

NSLog(@"%@", cats);
```

So again, the nested collections created when you read in the plist are fully initialized, and mutable to boot, so you can simply use them, as you've been doing.

**EDIT**

However, after doing some further reading of the docs, I think the OP is right to feel uneasy about relying on what is apparently an undocumented feature of the current version of the SDK. For example, the *Property List Programming Guide* states:

> If you load the property list with
>   this call:
>
> ```
> NSMutableArray * ma = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:xmlFile];
> ```
>
> `ma` is a mutable array with immutable
>   dictionaries in each element. Each key
>   and each value in each dictionary are
>   immutable.

So, to be on the safe side, if you need a nested collection to be mutable, you should create it yourself. For example, I'd recommend rewriting the code in the example above as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary *pets = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/Pets.plist"];
NSArray *cats = [pets objectForKey:@"cats"];

NSMutableArray *mutableCats = [cats mutableCopy];
[pets setObject:mutableCats forKey:cats];

[mutableCats release];
```

You can then safely make changes to the nested mutable collection:

```
[mutableCats addObject:@"Foo"];
```

Comment: Could you explain the significance of your "experiment" code? I don't understand how this would confirm that nested collections are initialized and mutable and ready to go (unless there was pertinent content in your plist that you just haven't shared). Thanks!

Comment: Well, I know I can create a nested collection manually, but that seems rather inefficient (or extremely inefficient) for complex data structures. Surely there's a way to use a plist to create a dictionary with mutable sub-dictionaries? Some sort of processing you can do on it once it's imported?